# Cannot use ndk-build on Cygwin

Tags: android, cygwin, android-ndk

I have to use NDK for a clien't project. I am using Windows 7.

I followed the installation instructions. I have installed Cygwin 1.7.1.

In Cygwin bash, I go into the android NDK root directory.

When I see the contents of the directory, usin $dir command, I can see all the contents including ndk-build, but when I try to use ndk-build, this is the result I get:

$ndk-build
bash: ndk-build: command not found.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @svens : That worked, Thanks! If you were to give that as an answer, I would do an 'accept' on that. Looks like I am atleast a step closer as there is a different error showing up now : "Please install Cygwin make package or define the GNUMAKE variable to point to it"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Cygwin emulates a GNU/Linux environment on your Windows computer. This means you're working with a "Shell" which is not exactly the same as the Windows command-line.

If you type `asdf.exe` in your Windows command-line, it tries to find asdf.exe in the current directory. If it can find it, the file is executed. If it can't find it, it'll go through every directory of your `%PATH%` and try again.

However, if you type `asdf` in your bash (there are multiple kind of shells, the Bourne Again SHell is one of them), it will **not** look after it in the current directory. Instead it'll try to find it in one of your `PATH` directories. Can't give you any sources here, but AFAIK it's for security reasons. If you want to run a file which is not in your `PATH`, you must prepend it with its absolute of relative path. You can use `./`, it points to the current directory.

That's why you need to type `./ndk-build`, because it's in the current directory and not your path. Something like `/path/to/ndk/ndk-build` will also work, but you have to type a bit more :).

(In fact it's even more complicated, if you want to execute a file, you need execute permissions for it. Google will help you if you have any problems with that.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, reminds me of the CLASSPATH in java, which doesn't look at the current directory unless you specifically ask it to. **voteup**