# ndk-build not found in cygwin

Tags: android-ndk, cygwin

I'm trying to use ndk-build in cygwin but for some reason, it isn't able to find the command.

I've tried to add the path of the NDK to PATH Environment variable as shown. I'm able to invoke ndk-build from command-line but cannot do so in cygwin.

[image]

Then as suggested from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797509/cannot-use-ndk-build-on-cygwin), I've tried to run ndk-build by appending ./ in front. Still doesn't work.

As a last resort, I edited .bash_profile's path so that it points to the NDK directory. Again, it doesn't work.

**SIGH.......** I'd appreciate any guidance.

[image]

Comment: The lines to set your path in your .bash_profile are commented out.

Comment: OH.. man I'm so stupid, I will remove the comment and see if it works

Comment: Well according to this .bash_profile, this is executed only if folder ${HOME}/bin exists. Is that your case?

Comment: I only uncommented the path part, so it should execute regardless.

Comment: Remove that trailing/blank space in the folder where the ndk is installed.

Comment: Wow.. that fixed it. Thanks! I'm pretty bewildered on why cygwin cannot handle blank spaces in directories properly though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove that trailing/blank space in the folder where the ndk is installed.

See [Android NDK: No rule to make target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243047/android-ndk-no-rule-to-make-target) for a similar problem.